# Swipe to Delete: deletes 2 items in Column

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've implemented a Swipe to Delete Feature, which is mostly working fine. However, it consistently deletes two items at a time instead of just one.

I suspect the issue stems from the fact that the tutorial I followed used a LazyColumn with the items() function, which allowed them to initialize a key parameter to solve the problem.

In my case, I'm displaying groups of items within a LazyColumn, with each group represented by a Column for each day containing individual items. Since Columns don't have the items() function, I've used foreach instead. As a result, there's no key parameter available, making it difficult to address the problem.

```
LazyColumn{
    items(groupedTransactions.keys.toList(), key = { it.toString() }) { date ->
        TransactionDayGroup(date = date, transactions = groupedTransactions[date]!!.toMutableList(), navController = navController)
    }
}

@Composable
fun TransactionDayGroup(date: LocalDate, transactions: MutableList<TransactionDetails>, navController: NavHostController) {
    val vm: TransactionViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModelProvider.Factory)
    Card (modifier = Modifier
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
        .padding(8.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(4.dp),)
    {
        Column {
            Text(text = DateUtils.formatDay(date), style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium, color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant)
            transactions.forEach { transaction ->
                Divider()
                SwipeToDeleteContainer(item = transaction, onDismiss = {
                    transactions.remove(transaction)
                    vm.deleteTransaction(Transaction(
                        id = transaction.id,
                        name = transaction.name,
                        amount = transaction.amount,
                        categoryId = transaction.category.id,
                        date = transaction.date,
                        description = transaction.description,
                        recurringIntervalUnit = transaction.recurringIntervalUnit,
                        recurringInterval = transaction.recurringInterval,
                        recurring = transaction.recurring
                    ))
                }) {
                    TransactionItem(transaction = transaction, navController = navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!